# paypal-sdk - Sorry, we can’t complete your purchase at this time

Tags: php, paypal, checkout

I was trying to implement checkout using the PayPal SDK but unfortunately I just can't get it to run properly. It only works when I have only one item in the cart which seems weird.
I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with my configuration but the documentation online is pretty scarce so here's my code

```
$payer = new Payer();
$details = new Details();
$amount = new Amount();
$transaction = new Transaction();
$payment = new Payment();
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();

// Payer
$payer -> setPaymentMethod("paypal");

$total = 0;

foreach ($cart as $item => $quantity) {
   //this loop just aggregates the total for the purchase

    $total += $quantity * $price;
}

// Details
$details -> setShipping("0.00")
    -> setTax("0.00")
    -> setSubtotal($total);

// Amount
$amount -> setCurrency("USD")
    -> setTotal($total)
    -> setDetails($details);

// Transaction
$transaction
    -> setAmount($amount)
    -> setDescription("Analysis & Development");

// Payment
$payment -> setIntent("sale")
    -> setPayer($payer)
    -> setTransactions([$transaction]);

// Redirect URLs
$redirectUrls -> setReturnUrl($base_url."php/pay.php?approved=true")
    -> setCancelUrl($base_url."php/pay.php?approved=false");

$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

try {

    $payment->create($api);

    // code to save transaction temporarily omitted

} catch (Exception $e) {
    header("Location: ../checkout.php?error=".$e->getMessage());
    die();
}

foreach ($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
    if($link->getRel() == "approval_url")
        $redirectUrl = $link -> getHref();
}

header("location: ".$redirectUrl);
```

When I get to the sandbox, I get "Sorry, we can’t complete your purchase at this time" with a button to go back to my website

Comment: Can you log the JSOn request response ?

Comment: @RahulDighe how may I do that please?

Comment: can you debug by stepping into this statement $payment->create($api); at some point a JSON will have to be generated. Also where is your code where you are adding items something like this - http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html ?

Answer (score 0):

vbtheory,

You're not initializing "**$price**" variable. Could you please check & initialize it. If issue still persists, then contact PayPal technical team for better & quick assistance:

https://www.paypal-techsupport.com